# How can I portray my lm() model across different ggplot scatterplot differently?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, rdd, lm

I am currently regressing GDP on multiple factors (7 different variables to be exact), My x variable is quarterly Dates (2006-Q1 to 2020-Q4). I need need to plot my scatter plot for the GDP with Date and plot my lm() linear line on top of it. I can not use geom_smooth() as it wont include all the regression coefficients and i can't do it any other way and am stuck. I attempted to use predict but when plotted its a non linear line. To sum it up, I need to take my lm() model and put it on my scatterplot.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is plot the distribution as a scatter and then create a set of points using predefined x values and calculate the y values based on the coefficients of the lm() model then change the visualization of it to be as lines. if you chose enough x values (100 for example), it will look like a curve.

Here is an example:

```
x0 <- seq(0,1,length.out = 25)
y0 <- x0^2 + 2*x0 + 3 + runif(n = 25, min = 0, max = 1)
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=x0, y=y0, type="scatter", mode = "markers")
```

[image]

Now we can calculate the quadratic regression and plot a set of points, using the coefficients to obtain the curves.

```
x0_2 <- x0^2
linreg <- lm(y0~x0+x0_2)

x1 <- seq(min(x0), max(x0), length.out = 100)
y1 <- x1*x1*linreg[["coefficients"]][3] + x1*linreg[["coefficients"]][2] + linreg[["coefficients"]][1]
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=x0, y=y0, type="scatter", mode = "markers") %>% add_lines(x=x1, y=y1, type="scatter", mode = "lines")
```

[image]